# Not getting enough Hashrate

Tags: hash

I have an i3-3220 processor which i am using for mining. 
I know that you're supposed to use a GPU and all that. But currently i'm just trying it out before spending money.

I'm using CPUMiner, mining at middlecoin.com, 24 hours a day.

The problem is that i'm recieving very less hashrate.
This https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison points out that an i3 processor (which is actually a lower model than mine) recieves almost 8.5 MH/s and i receive about 5.5 KH/s on each thread that is about 27 KH/s in total.Why such a large difference?

What do i need to tweak? Is my program useless? Are the settings wrong? Is it problem with the pool?

Comment: You should provide the exact model of your CPU and what your command line is.

Comment: Which program? Which settings? Which pool? You ask questions without even giving the baseline information. EVER asked anyone for help on anything? You should know better. Give us at least some basic infos.

Comment: TomTom. Didn't i mention CPUMiner? I did. Pool? Come on. Middlecoin.com has only one pool. Settings? I didn't tweak anything at all. Just using the default settings. The settings or tweaks part is what i wanna know... You should tell me that.

Comment: Colin: i3-3220? Is there a more exact CPU version? If yes, then how do i find that?

Comment: @ColinDean the i3-3220 is the model number, enough for exact specs of this chip [see summary article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_Core_i3_microprocessors) and [Intel's page for the CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/65693)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** (From comments, this was the real issue):

Are you doing Litecoin or Bitcoin mining? Looks like middlecoin.com does Litecoin. The hash rate for Litecoin will be much slower due to the scrypt algorithm, which is slower to process than Bitcoin sha2. The bitcoin.it wiki page is showing hashrates for Bitcoin mining.  That would explain the 1000x factor difference.

**EDIT**:  (first answer)

<strike>When was the chart made?  Those results captured on that page would have been accurate when the cumulative mining strength of the network was at a particular difficulty.  Note that the difficulty is increasing quite rapidly so whatever you're using for mining is less effective than previous.</strike>

From comments below, I'm missing the point a bit, thanks for the clarifications.  Specifically, a device's hashrate remains the same no matter what difficulty the network is at.

Comment: You're right Chris. The difficulty decreases because everone's hashrate is increasing. But that doesn't change an individual's hashrate. It just decreases his share.

Comment: What i want to know here is why i'm not getting enough hashrate?

Comment: @HarryKing Do you have a resource monitor app for your OS?  Like Task Manager or Activity Monitor.  Do they show at/near 100% CPU utilization?  Actually maybe just a little over 50% might be the max, you have a dual-core system with hyperthreading, and I'm guessing CPUminer uses SSE instructions (so no benefit from hyperthreaded "cores").

Comment: I'm on windows 8. The windows 8 taskmanager shows CPU activity. And yes, it shows near 100% CPU activity. To be precise, it fluctuates between 95% to 98%. Mostly at 98%.

Comment: Looks like CPUminer supports two architectures `x86` and `x86-64`, with Win8 you probably want the better one (or at least newer ;-) `x86-64`.  As an experiment, can you try the other version than what you have installed?  (maybe a bug with detecting your exact CPU capabilities)  Also I can't tell if CPUminer has any diagnostics, would be interesting to know if it is trying to detect support for AVX or SSE2 and failing, thus causing it to run slower for compatibility.

Comment: And another experiment, try `--threads=2` on your command line, to see if that helps at all (theory is that you only have two "real cores" so no point running 4 threads waiting on two SIMD units).

Comment: Its already running four threads actually. Each at a little over 5 KH/s. I have no technical knowledge about avx or sse2. Care to explain?

Comment: And i already have the x64 one.

Comment: The AVX (newer) and SSE2 are both a set of extensions to the Intel instruction set, for SIMD tasks, single instruction multiple data.  Each real core will have an SIMD unit, 8 larger registers where you can do the same instruction to all 8 in parallel, this gives a nice performance boost for data-parallel applications such as the SHA2 processing used during mining.  Compare this with the traditional floating point unit of the CPU, which can only one such operation at a time, not 8.  But do try the setting the max threads to two instead of the default 4, just a hunch.

Comment: OK... and how do i do that?

Comment: Waitasecond, are you doing Litecoin or Bitcoin mining?  Looks like middlecoin.com does Litecoin.  The hash rate for Litecoin will be much slower due to the scrypt algorithm, which is slower to process than Bitcoin sha2.  The bitcoin.it wiki page is showing hashrates for Bitcoin mining.

Comment: yes, middlecoin.com mines scrypt coins. Confusion cleared.

Comment: All this aside do you know how to speed up the hashrate.
Should i try using linux (ubuntu) instead or drivers or some tweaks?
You don't need to explain a lot. If you know any links..I can help myself.